# Deleting image files within a directory (That might be used by another process)

Tags: vb.net

How can i delete image files (ex *.gif) that might be in use, by another process in a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete it, while another process is using it. This comes from low-level file handling of Windows. However you can play around with renaming the file or setting it to be deleted on next boot.

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) tool can help you finding which process is using the file and it can actually close the handle - given proper/administrative rights. So it is possible with API calls, but such forced close of file handle can result in unpredictable behavior of that process.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't delete it, you might be able to rename it, but I'm not sure why some locked files can be renamed while others can't.

You can also schedule it to be deleted at next boot using MoveFileEx with a null destination and the MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT flag: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240(VS.85).aspx 
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/MoveFileEx.html 
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/MoveFileFlags.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile, you can notify the user of what program has the file locked if another program is using the file.  It can't be deleted if it's in use.

```
Try
   My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Documents and Settings\anybody\Desktop\dummy.doc", _
                                     FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, _
                                     FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently, _
                                     FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException)
Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
   Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
End Try
```